# What is the best re-usable solution for serving complex content (think an entire tree of web pages) from one web app to another website?

Tags: javascript, iframe, widget, jsonp, embedding

**Our goal** is to let a person, similarly to how you can embed a youtube video, **embed a tree of web pages on our SaaS into their own site**.

The solution should be `good looking`, `cross-browser`, `responsive` and `simple` for the end user (ideally, should be `search-bot friendly` as well).

---

We are considering two primary options where the customer only needs to `copy+paste` a code snippet which supports embedding in a portion of the page (ex: the middle column) or full width (ex: everything under a header):

1. **IFRAME**: Let the user embed an iframe inside a div, together with a snippet of `JS` that would resize the iframe as the window is resized.
2. **JS "APP"**: Let the user paste in a script tag to a `JS` script/app which would communicate cross-domain (via CORS or JSONP) with our servers.

Ideally, we would like to be able to launch full screen modals from our content.

Questions/concerns for:

**IFRAME**:

- Can an iframe reliably update the URL of the parent’s browser window?
- Can we reliably launch full screen modals from an iframe?
- Can we reliably get the iframe to resize when the window is resized or iframe content changes?

**JS "APP"**:

- How significant is the overhead of dealing with properly encapsulating our app to avoid naming/library conflicts? For example, we will ideally stick to vanilla JS but if we want to use a library like Ember and a customer of ours has an Ember site.
- Any non-obvious cross domain gotchas? We will be using CORS or JSONP.

---

We would like input on both the:

1. technical limitations of what’s possible to do
2. practical hurdles we’d have to overcome going down each path.

---

p.s. We’re also considering a back-up option, which is to “fake” integration, where we host the content on our site with a subdomain URL (similarly to how Tumblr lets people host their blog on something like “apple.tumblr.com”). If we go down this path we imagine letting the user theme the subdomain. We understand the pros and cons of this path. Downsides are, it’s more work for the user, and they need to keep two different sites in sync visually.

Comment: If you want the content to be visible to search-bots (which you haven't mentioned at all), than it has to be script and you have to use `document.write`. Also, you forgot [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) method, which is the future of cross-domain messaging.

Comment: @skobaljic Ideally the content would be visible to search-bots. Thanks for the note regarding postMessage, I'll take a look. Appreciate the comment.

Comment: Few months ago I read [this article](http://moz.com/ugc/can-google-really-access-content-in-javascript-really), it may help you.

Comment: Also [this interview](http://www.stonetemple.com/articles/interview-matt-cutts-012510.shtml), maybe 4th question from below and some other stuff in there...

Comment: It sounds like you have a clear cut set of requirements and a few test cases. I would hire a front-end technical consultant to help you determine the best approach given your specific needs. If you can't do that, I would investigate each approach you have outlined a bit more in-depth and make a decision. You really aren't going to be able to answer this until you get your hands dirty and code out these approaches and see what works best for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to use the same approach Google and other big companies have been using for quite some time, the embedded script. It is way better looking and semantically unharmful (as an `iframe` could - arguably - be), and super cross-browser and simple, in fact, just as cross-browser and simple as the code that will be pushed (it can be recommended to be put in a `<script async>` tag, which will eliminate the need for a crafted async script  and, though it won't be as full compatible, it degrades okay and will work very well on most cases).

As to the CORS, if basic cautions are taken, there's no need to worry a lot about it. I would say, though, that if you're planning to do something in Ember or Angular to be embedded, that may be a whole load of scripts/bytes that can even slow down the site/app and impact on the whole user experience, perhaps too much for a component that would be loaded like that. So whenever possible, vanilla JS should always be used in components, especially if Ember/Angular is used because of specific features like binding (specific vanilla JS codes can cover that with much less weight).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm coming to the same conclusion. iFrame is "easy" but isn't as flexible. JS is flexible but likely more work. Going to take some more time to digest. Appreciate your perspective. Cheers.